# Header/title missing for `PreferenceScreen` in Android

Tags: android

I am very new to Android and i am having trouble displaying a header for my `PreferenceScreen` activity. I want to display a title like this

[image]

My class declaration goes like this

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
```

and `onCreate`like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, _settingsFragment).commit(); 
}
```

Preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:key="pref_key_vault_storage"
        android:title="Vault Storage"
        android:summary="Set/modify the vault storage location." >
        <intent
            android:targetPackage="com.test.concealx"
            android:targetClass="com.test.concealx.ChooseStorageActivity"/>
    </Preference>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:id="@+id/id_path"
        android:title="Vault Path"
        android:key="pref_key_vault_path"
        android:summary="Set/modify the storage path. DO NOT change this unless you are sure about it.">
    </EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

What i get now is this

[image]

I have already tried `android:title="My Settings"` and `setTitle` on the PreferenceActivity to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714971/6050536

Comment: @Ali I tried that and it's not working either :-(

Answer (score 0):

Change PreferenceActivity to AppCompatPretenceActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
```

You need to set ActionBar like this becauase the title is displayed on it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, _settingsFragment).commit(); 


     Toolbar toolbar;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
            toolbar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
            root.addView(toolbar, 0);
        } else {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            ListView content = (ListView) root.getChildAt(0);
            root.removeAllViews();
            toolbar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
            int height;
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
                height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            } else {
                height = toolbar.getHeight();
            }
            content.setPadding(0, height, 0, 0);
            root.addView(content);
            root.addView(toolbar);
        }
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

settings_toolbar.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    />
```

Comment: That will only show as a group title, not the main/activity level header

Comment: try this now. create a toolbar and set it as ActionBar

Comment: `toolbar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(thi...` is throwing `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar`. I am on Android 6.0.1

Comment: extend AppCompatPreferenceActivity and use setSupportActionBar() to set the toolbar. (See edit)